# Is there any size limit for Spark-Dataframe to process/hold columns at a time?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to know, whether Spark-Dataframe has a limitation on Column Size ? Like max columns that can be processed/hold by a Dataframe at a time is less than 500. I am asking because, while parsing a xml with less than 500 tags, I can process and generate a corresponding parquet file successfully, but if it is more than 500, then the parquet getting generated is empty. Any idea on this ?

Comment: I think the only limit is in memory since anything more then 500 will take a lot to process.